# Only allow user to create one feedback for each movies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionview

I have three models, `User`, `Movie`, and `Review`. Here is the relation:

```
# User.rb
has_many :movies
has_many :reviews

# Movie.rb
belongs_to :user
has_many :reviews

# Review.rb
belongs_to :movies
belongs_to :users
```

Here is the routes:

```
# routes.rb
resources :movies do
 resources :reviews
end
```

Here is the controller:

```
# reviews_controller.rb
class ReviewsController < ApplicationController
  before_action authenticate_user!
  before_action :find_movie
  before_action :find_review, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  def new
    @review = Review.new
  end

  def create
    @review = Review.new(review_params)

    if @review.save
      redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @review.update(review_params)
      redirect_to movie_path(@movie)
    end
  end

  private
    def find_movie
      @movie = Movie.find(params[:movie_id])
    end

    def find_review
      @review = Review.find(params[:id])
    end

    def review_params
      params.require(:review).permit(:rating, :comment)
    end
end
```

I created a new and partial form and then in the show page of the movie, I create this line of code to show the button of creating new review for a particular movie:

```
# views/movies/show.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Give review', new_movie_review_path(@movie) %>
```

I don't want the user to create another review after they submit a review for the same movie. That's why I want to hide the "Give review" button if the user is already gave the feedback. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
<% unless current_user.reviews.select{|review| review.movie_id == @movie.id}.count > 0 %>
  <%= link_to 'Give review', new_movie_review_path(@movie) %>
<% end %>
```

Could also use where instead:

```
Review.where(user_id: current_user.id, movie_id: @movie.id).count > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the `current_user` available to views then you can have something like the following to hide Give Review link:

```
# views/movies/show.html.erb
<%= link_to 'Give review', new_movie_review_path(@movie) unless current_user.movies.where(id: @movie.id).first.comments.any? %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add a [custom validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) in the review model which checks for a preexisting review from the same user for the same movie.